# Jenkins Blue Ocean Plugin fails to connect to GitHub

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

I'm trying to create a Jenkins pipeline using Blue Ocean but when I try to connect to my GitHub using the GitHub generated access token, nothing happens. However, when I check the console, I get this error message. Someone please help me out.

[image: Here is an image of the console]

```
blueocean.js:58216 Unhandled Rejection: "Error: fetch failed: 500 for http://127.0.0.1:8090/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/scm/github/validate/?apiUrl=https://api.github.com\n at FetchFunctions.checkStatus (http://127.0.0.1:8090/adjuncts/49720cc1/io/jenkins/blueocean/blueocean-core-js.js:54923:25)" lo
gUnhandledPromiseRejection @ blueocean.js:58216
```

At the network tab, the response is:

```
  "message" : "No 'injectableValues' configured, cannot inject value with id [org.kohsuke.github.GitHubResponse$ResponseInfo]\
```

Comment: I have the same problem with a Jenkins instance I installed today. The error coming back from the web service call is.`No 'injectablevalues' configured`

Comment: Yeah I can see the same error from the network tab

Comment: Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: There's an issue on JIRA. Someone got it working by downgrading Github API, but I haven't tried it myself: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61822?focusedCommentId=388713&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-388713

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue was with the version of blue ocean I had installed. I downgraded to 1.106. You can do the following to sort the issue.

Grab the 1.106. version of the plugin from [Here](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/github-api/)

Then go to manage plugins > Advance > Upload Plugin and upload the 1.106 plugins and install it. All dependencies and indirect dependencies will also be satisfied with this version.

For more information check [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61822?focusedCommentId=388713&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-388713)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading GitHub API to 1.106 worked for me.